# Compile static library in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013 to develop c++ static libraries *.lib. I got a request to compile the library using Visual Studio 2010 compiler, however I do not have it installed on the developer machine.

When compiling dynamic library *.dll it is possible to use switch /MT that will pack the C runtime into dll. The dynamic library thus becomes larger. However, when I use the /MT switch the static library becomes smaller (5MB -> 4.9MB) which is against what I would expect.

Question:
1. Can I build static library in Visual Studio 2013, so that it can be later used by Visual Studio 2010 compiler?
2. Is the /MT switch the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static libraries are in general only compatible with the toolset that built them. This is especially true of any use of the Standard C++ Library / STL, which is why newer versions of VS have the `_MSC_VER` stamp embedded for any use of the STL headers that will generate link-time errors if you attempt to mix them.

It is also important that static libraries be built with the same CRT settings (/MT, /MD, /MTd, /MDd) as the project that is consuming them.

DLLs using C or COM exports using the CRT DLL are really the only 'stable' library that can be mixed with different versions of the compiler safely.

Otherwise, you should obtain the toolset for every version you want to support and build all desired flavors of the .lib.